# How to do block repetition in Regex

Tags: java, regex

Suppose the source string is

```
(Adam)/NNP Apple/NN Orange/NN banana/NN tall/JJ
```

My regular expression is to detect NNP followed by any number of NN it does not matter how much

if I did the following,

```
[a-zA-z]*/NNP\s[a-zA-z]*/NN\s[a-zA-z]*/NN\s[a-zA-z]*/NN\s[a-zA-z]*/JJ
```

I will restrict my self to three nouns after NNP while I want it any number of NN or even zero

How can I do that in regex?

Comment: why not `[a-zA-z]*/NNP\s[a-zA-z]*(/NN\s[a-zA-z]*)*/JJ`?

Comment: Actually I want to detect NNP by using group tall. So, I am going to write as you and add ([a-zA-z]*)/NNP\s[a-zA-z]*(/NN\s[a-zA-z]*)*/JJ I will get two groups? How the computer will know which part contains the NNP.. because I am doing that automatically in java

Comment: Maybe I need to post another question for this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUPS

```
[a-zA-z]*/NNP(\s[a-zA-z]*/NN)+\s[a-zA-z]*/JJ 

(any character sequence)+
+ - repeat this sequence one or more time.
```

For more details see documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg